# Reading a string from one char to another

Tags: c#, string, character

I have the following string:

> FB:77:CB:0B:EC:09{W: 0,623413, X: 0,015374, Y: 0,005306, Z: -0,781723}

I want to read out the values of W,X,Y,Z as a float/decimal. The values are not always the same length.

How can I read this string from one character to another without using relative positions?

Comment: I would use regex

Comment: This string seems to me like an incorrect JSON string. What is the nature of this string?

Comment: It comes from an IMU, the values represent the orientation in Quaternion. Before this is the MacAdress of the IMU, eg FB:77:CB:0B:EC:09

Comment: Do you just want an integer? As in `W = 0`, `X = 0`, `Y = 0` and `Z = 0`?

Comment: As Aldert says, this may well be a good place to try a regex. You may find you can create a regex more easily if you first strip off the { and the characters before that, and the trailing }.

Comment: You shall post multiple sample data? For example if  W,X,Y,Z are fixed in each line then solution will be very simple?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest matching the "inner" part with a regular expression, but removing the "outer" part manually first - just to keep the regex as simple as possible.

Here's a complete example, with a method that returns the result as a `Dictionary<string, string>`. It's not clear how you'd then want to convert the sample values you've given (e.g. "0,623413") into integers, but I'd treat that as a separate task from the initial parsing.

I'm assuming that it's fine to strip all trailing commas from values:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "FB:77:CB:0B:EC:09{W: 0,623413, X: 0,015374, Y: 0,005306, Z: -0,781723}";
        var parsed = Parse(input);
        foreach (var entry in parsed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key = '{entry.Key}', Value = '{entry.Value}'");
        }        
    }

    static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<key>[A-Z]+): (?<value>[-\d,]+)");
    static IDictionary<string, string> Parse(string input)
    {
        int openBrace = input.IndexOf('{');
        if (openBrace == -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected input to contain a {");
        }
        if (!input.EndsWith("}"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected input to end with }");
        }
        string inner = input.Substring(openBrace + 1, input.Length - openBrace - 2);
        var matches = regex.Matches(inner);
        return matches.Cast<Match>()
            .ToDictionary(match => match.Groups["key"].Value,
                          match => match.Groups["value"].Value.TrimEnd(','));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Key = 'W', Value = '0,623413'
Key = 'X', Value = '0,015374'
Key = 'Y', Value = '0,005306'
Key = 'Z', Value = '-0,781723'
```

Converting those values to integers *may* be as simple as removing the commas, trimming leading zeroes, and then using `int.Parse` - but it really depends on what you want the results to be.

Comment: Very good answer @JonSkeet. I have a suggestion, In your Parse method why not using an IEnumerable<(string, string)> instead of a dictionary?

Comment: @ZackISSOIR: Because it's more naturally a dictionary of key/value pairs, IMO. I think it's not unlikely that the OP may well want to look up the values by key.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this method will do:

```
int GetIntValue(string input, char prefix)
{
  return int.Parse(input.Substring(input.IndexOf($"{prefix}: ") + 3, 1));
}
```

This will, however, return `0` for all of your sample input. The reason why we only parse the zero is that they'll be ignored by the int parser anyway.

If, as I suspect, you don't want an integer but instead the full number, use something like this:

```
decimal GetValue(string input, char prefix)
{
  return decimal.Parse(input.Substring(input.IndexOf($"{prefix}: ") + 3).Split(new[] { ", ", "}" }, StringSplitOptions.None).First());
}
```

Feel free to replace `decimal` with whatever you would like.

Call it like this:

```
var input = "FB:77:CB:0B:EC:09{W: 0,623413, X: 0,015374, Y: 0,005306, Z: -0,781723}";
var W = GetValue(input, 'W'); // 0.623413
var X = GetValue(input, 'X'); // 0.015374
var Y = GetValue(input, 'Y'); // 0.005306
var Z = GetValue(input, 'Z'); // -0.781723
```

What this does is to identify the location of the prefix, and then parse a substring from the beginning of the following number until the delimiter (`,` or `}`) has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        string str = "FB:77:CB:0B:EC:09{W: 0,623413, X: 0,015374, Y: 0,005306, Z: -0,781723}";
        char[] delims = { ':', ' ' };

        var parsed = Parse(str, delims);

        foreach (var p in parsed) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{p.Key} : {p.Value}");
        }
    }

    static Dictionary<string, double> Parse(string input, char[] delims) {
        int first = input.IndexOf('{') + 1;
        int second = input.IndexOf('}');
        string str2 = input.Substring(first, second - first);

        string[] strArray = str2.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Dictionary<string, double> pairs = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        for (int i = 1; i < strArray.Length; i++) {
            if (double.TryParse(strArray[i].TrimEnd(','), out double result)) {
                pairs.Add(strArray[i - 1], result);
            }

            i++;
        }

        return pairs;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We need long answers that provide some detail.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another Regex example that parses number to decimal and includes plus and negative sign.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "FB:77:CB:0B:EC:09{W: 0,623413, X: 0,015374, Y: 0,005306, Z: -0,781723}";
            string pattern = @"W:\s*(?'W'[-+]?\d+,\d+),\s*X:\s*(?'X'[-+]?\d+,\d+),\s*Y:\s*(?'Y'[-+]?\d+,\d+),\s*Z:\s*(?'Z'[-+]?\d+,\d+)";
            CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo("en");
            info.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

            decimal W = decimal.Parse(match.Groups["W"].Value, info);
            decimal X = decimal.Parse(match.Groups["X"].Value, info);
            decimal Y = decimal.Parse(match.Groups["Y"].Value, info);
            decimal Z = decimal.Parse(match.Groups["Z"].Value, info);

        }
    }
}
```